# c++ struct loop error

Tags: c++, struct, io

This code  runs fine but the for statement by the "meant to read back struct line by line for each" comment code at the bottom doesn't work as it should, it is meant to list items, with prices for each seat, outputting seat# before the list of items for each seat, the seat number part works

EDIT: the error is it shows item in the readout loop to be undeclared, causing this to not compile

`line 64 'item' undeclared (first use this function)`

` in above string changed to ' for code highlight function

Program being used Dev-C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int N_ITEMS;
int N_SEATS;
int seat;
int tItems;

struct ITM_TYPE {
   int seatN;
   string name;
   float price;
};

int dash(int n)
{
  int i = 0;
  while(i < (n))
  {
    cout << "-";
    i++;
  }
  cout << "\n";
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
cout << "Enter the number of seats: "; 
cin >> N_SEATS; //retrieve number of seats
N_SEATS += 1;
for(seat = 1; seat < N_SEATS; seat++) // loop for each seat
{
    cout << "Enter number of items for seat" << seat <<": ";
    cin >> N_ITEMS; //get number of items for seat
    tItems += N_ITEMS;
    ITM_TYPE item[N_ITEMS]; //make N number of item structs
    int i = 0;
    string name;
    float price;
    while (i < N_ITEMS)
    {
        item[i].seatN = seat;            //blah blah retrive and add data to stucts
        cout << "Input item name: ";
        cin >> name;
        item[i].name = name;
        cout << "item[" << i << "].name SET" << endl;
        cout << "Input item price: ";
        cin >> price;
        item[i].price = price;
        cout << "item[" << i << "].price SET" << endl;
        i++;
    }
}
for(seat = 1; seat < N_SEATS; seat++) //meant to read back struct line by line for each item
{
    cout << "seat" << seat << endl;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < tItems)
    {
        if (item[i].seatN == seat){cout << item[i].name << "    " << item[i].price << endl;}
        //cout << item[i].name << endl;
        i++;
    }
}
   system("pause");
}
```

Comment: What does it do that it shouldn't?

Comment: oh should have added that :/
it says item is undeclared yet earlier in main it is used.

Comment: oh my many-legged gods! i cannot rest in disgusted silence after seeing you using global variables for a loop variable. I have to get down the bus just to tell you sir; i have the greatest contempt for your COBOLized pseudo-c sample, i really do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through your code line-by-line in Visual Studio. It works now. Commented all my changes and why.

**updated version using STL : http://pastebin.com/CYvX9yrn**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
// !! You had no use for iomanip

using namespace std;

struct ITM_TYPE 
{
    std::string name;
    float price;
    int seatN;
};

// !! You had an unused function here

int main()
{
    // !! These had no business being global variables
    int N_ITEMS;
    int N_SEATS;
    int seat;
    // !! You did not initialize this before using it
    int tItems = 0;

    cout << "Enter the number of seats: "; 
    cin >> N_SEATS; //retrive number of seats

    // !! This is not needed if you iterate starting at 0
    N_SEATS += 1;

    // !! You can not dynamically create arrays like you did. Do it like below
    // !! Also you used N_ITEMS incorrectly as opposed to N_SEATS
    // !! This was also out of scope inside the for (the second for did not know it existed)
    // !! Plus it was being re-created on every iteration
    ITM_TYPE* item = new ITM_TYPE[ N_SEATS ];

    for( seat = 1; seat < N_SEATS; seat++ ) // loop for each seat
    {
        cout << "Enter number of items for seat" << seat <<": ";
        cin >> N_ITEMS; //get number of items for seat
        tItems += N_ITEMS;

        string name;
        float price;

        // !! If you are initializing an iterator variable, then incrementing on each
        // !! loop, then just use a for instead of a while. Thats why it exists
        for( int i = 0; i < N_ITEMS; i++ )
        {
            item[i].seatN = seat;            //blah blah retrive and add data to stucts

            cout << "Input item name: ";
            cin >> name;
            item[i].name = name;

            cout << "item[" << i << "].name SET" << endl;
            cout << "Input item price: ";
            cin >> price;
            item[i].price = price;

            cout << "item[" << i << "].price SET" << endl;
        }
    }

    for( seat = 1; seat < N_SEATS; seat++ ) //meant to read back struct line by line for each item
    {
        cout << "seat" << seat << endl;

        // !! Like the previous ex-while loop, for is much better for the situation
        for(int i = 0; i < tItems; i++ )
        {
            // !! This was just hard to read how you had it
            if( item[i].seatN == seat )
                cout << item[i].name << "    " << item[i].price << endl;
        }
    }

    // !! Destroy our item array to prevent memory leak
    delete[ ] item;

    system( "pause" );

    // !! You did not indicate a successful end of program
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: wow I totally forgot `return 0;`
it is in the code but i removed large commented out sections and apparently that with it

Comment: Also, stop using Dev-C++! Use a Visual C++ Express, or if you are a student get the full version free from [http://www.dreamspark.com](http://www.dreamspark.com). It will take a little getting used to, but it is superior in every single way.

Comment: Generally you should avoid naked `new` and `delete` in your code (too low-level, no exception safety, no automatic resource management etc.). The standard dynamic sequence container is `vector`, so just use that.

Comment: I have visual c++ express, I don't know if its just my mind playing tricks on me or if it compiles quicker, either way the reason I used Dev-C++ is that only half the school computers have Visual C++ Express

as for dreamspark, my school isnt on the list and they wont let me verify again :/ (school not on list, school email ends in edu.au, school ID can't be used) I tried asking my school to signup (both the head teacher and head of IT)

Comment: oh.....item gets set again in the next loop seat1 sets item[0] and item[1]
seat2 then goes and does the same.

Comment: @Philipp That is correct, and though I am a huge fan of `std::vector` I didn't want to add to any confusion by introducing a potentially new STL feature. Plus it stayed more true to what the original code was. @Arcticfoxx in my quick check, I did not even try multiple items. There are multiple solutions. Two of which: 1) Use a multi-dimensional array, where each row represents a seat or 2) Change `ITM_TYPE` to be able to hold multiple names, etc. I would suggest take Philipps advice and looking into  [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) if you are allowed to use STL.

Comment: ah ok I will look into vector, hopefully wont take to long to learn, this assignment is due monday

Thank you again

Comment: @Articfoxx I updated the code to work completely using STL objects (`vector` and `pair`). Take a look: [http://pastebin.com/CYvX9yrn](http://pastebin.com/CYvX9yrn)

Comment: iomanip was to later be used for `cout.setpresision(2)`

thanks for the code

thank you also vector seems easy (looked up tutorial) so i would use a vector for each item set in my struct 1 for name 1 for price ?

Comment: @Articfoxx Which is why I originally did not use any of the STL aside from `string` which you were already employing. Vector can be thought of as a dynamic array, ok? So I use one to hold all the seats, and another to hold the seat items (names,prices). I could have used a multi-dimensional array, but it easier programatically to use a `pair` which is simply two items paired together. So I have a dynamic array of pairings of names and prices. `ITM_TYPE.items[0].first` retrieves the name of the first item pair for that seat, and `ITM_TYPE.items[0].second` gets the price that goes with it.

Comment: ah ok, I'll try look at it and work it out if not I shall attempt to make my own way

Comment: `nItem.items.push_back( std::pair< std::string, float >( name, price ) );`

> and < are usually used for data flow so the `string, float >( name, price)` confuses me as you are putting string and float into name and price (with data flow and my perhaps failing logic)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8200/discussion-between-arcticfoxx-and-ssell)

Answer (score 1):

Move `ITM_TYPE item[N_ITEMS];` above your first `for` loop to get it to compile. `item` has gone out of scope by the time the next loop runs so it can't access it.

You are also never initialising `tItems` which will cause problems. Change:

```
int tItems;
```

to:

```
int tItems = 0;
```

Comment: @Arcticfoxx You never give it an initial value though, so you are adding `N_ITEMS` to what is effectively a random number. It is legal behaviour which is why the compiler accepts it, it is undefined though.

Comment: oh ok, I will add that then and try get into that habit, thanks.

Comment: @Arcticfoxx What's the exact error the compiler is reporting? You need to be more specific otherwise I can't help you.

Comment: added to the question 

`line 64 'item' undeclared (first use this function)`

Comment: @Arcticfoxx Where did you move the `ITM_TYPE item[N_ITEMS];` declaration to? If you put it immediately after `int main() {` it should work.

Comment: is it because the declaration is in the for loop, that its not working? also if so, how would I fix that, if you look at the code you can see that doesn't work really if i was to implement that, well at least i dont think so, as N_ITEMS is given value in the for loop

Comment: @Arcticfoxx You could create a two-dimensional array `ITM_TYPE item[N_SEATS][N_ITEMS];` outside the for loops then access it like this: `item[seat][i]`.

Comment: I shall try that, although another answer has been given, thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't know the total item size in advance, you cannot use a C array.  Avoiding them is recommended anyway, so you should rewrite your program to use a vector:

```
#include <vector>
// ...
vector<ITM_TYPE> item;
for(seat = 1; seat < N_SEATS; seat++) // loop for each seat
{
    cout << "Enter number of items for seat" << seat <<": ";
    cin >> N_ITEMS; //get number of items for seat
    tItems += N_ITEMS;
    item.reserve(tItems);
    int i = 0;
    string name;
    float price;
    while (i < N_ITEMS)
    {
        ITM_TYPE it;
        it.seatN = seat;            //blah blah retrive and add data to stucts
        cout << "Input item name: ";
        cin >> name;
        it.name = name;
        cout << "item[" << i << "].name SET" << endl;
        cout << "Input item price: ";
        cin >> price;
        it.price = price;
        cout << "item[" << i << "].price SET" << endl;
        item.push_back(it);
        i++;
    }
}
```

---

Here is a more idiomatic version of your code, using an item vector for each seat:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Item {
  int seatN;
  string name;
  float price;
};

template<typename Char, typename Traits>
basic_ostream<Char, Traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<Char, Traits>& stream, const Item& item) {
  return stream << item.name << "    " << item.price << endl;
}

struct Seat {
  vector<Item> items;
};

void dash(const unsigned int n) {
  cout << string(n, '-') << endl;
}

int main() {
  cout << "Enter the number of seats: "; 
  unsigned int seatCount;
  cin >> seatCount; //retrive number of seats
  vector<Seat> seats;
  seats.reserve(seatCount);
  for (unsigned int seatIndex = 0; seatIndex < seatCount; ++seatIndex) { // loop for each seat
    cout << "Enter number of items for seat " << seatIndex + 1 << ": ";
    unsigned int itemCount;
    cin >> itemCount; //get number of items for seat
    Seat seat;
    seat.items.reserve(itemCount);
    for (unsigned int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < itemCount; ++itemIndex) {
      Item item;
      item.seatN = seatIndex;            //blah blah retrive and add data to stucts
      cout << "Input item name: ";
      cin >> item.name;
      cout << "item[" << itemIndex << "].name SET" << endl;
      cout << "Input item price: ";
      cin >> item.price;
      cout << "item[" << itemIndex << "].price SET" << endl;
      seat.items.push_back(item);
    }
    seats.push_back(seat);
  }
  for (unsigned int seatIndex = 0; seatIndex < seatCount; ++seatIndex) { //meant to read back struct line by line for each item
    cout << "seat " << seatIndex + 1 << endl;
    const vector<Item>& items = seats[seatIndex].items;
    copy(items.begin(), items.end(), ostream_iterator<Item>(cout));
  }
}
```